# Como unir palabras y que se vuelvan mayúsculas java

Tags: java, bucles, string

quisiera que me ayuden en este trabajo, necesito que el programa me una las palabras y ademas las convierta en mayúsculas...ejemplo: hola amigo---->HOLAAMIGO...por favor necesito su ayuda...

```
         String ato = uno.getText();
         uno.setText(ato.toUpperCase());
         String atomo = tres.getText();
         tres.setText(atomo.replace(" ", ""));
```

Comment: Hiciste una pregunta de cadenas hoy, cuando recibiste una (buena) respuesta, en lugar de aceptarla o votar a favor por ella, eliminaste la pregunta. ¿Por qué ese comportamiento? Pregunto, porque creo que no te ayuda a obtener nuevas respuestas. Además, si entendiste el código anterior, creo que fácilmente podrías hacer esta otra tarea.

Comment: La pregunta eliminada [es esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/290792/21).

Comment: Veo que realizas preguntas y posteriormente las eliminas, te sugiero evitar esta práctica ya que los miembros de la comunidad tratan de ayudarte y es importante valores esa ayuda. Considera realizar el [tour] del sitio, es importante.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uno = "hola", dos = "que tal";
        /* el metodo replaceAll remplaza todos los caracteres ("estos",)
        por (,"estos"). \\s equivale a cualquier espacio en blanco */
        String tres = uno + dos.replaceAll("\\s","");
        // toUpperCase() pasa el texto a mayuscula
        System.out.println(tres.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```